# What are the forces acting on three boxes stacked on top of each other on the floor?

Tags: forces, gravity

i) What's the force acting on the bottom box? 
ii) What's the force acting on the box in the middle?

The surfaces on the boxes and the floor are smooth.

I can sort of understand the forces acting on the bottom box but I have a hard time understanding the reaction forces acting on the middle box.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 1):

All the boxes would experience the force of gravity as per the universal law of gravitation and each box would also experience normal reaction forces from anything with which it is in contact with.

You can even calculate them or find a relation between them by taking into consideration the mechanical equilibrium of boxes.

If you encounter any problem in that, you may post that specific problem here.